# Omniauth sign in adds extra port to auth url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, omniauth

I am using the `omniauth-facebook, omniauth-twitter, omniauth-google-oauth2` gems 
for signing in, on localhost everything works fine, but in production it adds the port number 5050 to the authorization url, has anybody encountered this problem?
My site url is addthis.com

**Twitter url**

http://addthis.com:5050/users/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=krnYyA5BzM4JlCc5XVxuhsdfspArsdfgtkrUzajMts&oauth_verifier=MjLR9fPSV7aWThOe80oDuPBpB6pvVdBijKMMLdxifR4

**Facebook url:**

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=213027215529249&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Faddthis.com%3A5050%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email&state=1bf3f21df9be97337asdfasdfsda4995bdf9982f321d

**Google url**

The redirect URI in the request: http://addthis.com:5050/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback did not match a registered redirect URI

Comment: I just tried logging in on your website with Twitter and it worked. I would also suggest that however weird, the error is rather in your code than the gem - it's widely used and properly tested.

Comment: I didnt want to publicize my real site url, so I changed the url, my website is not in english. www.socpost.net is my site

Comment: I don't really remember how Twitter oauth works, but My bet is that you set at some point redirect URL with :5050. When I try to log in with Twitter it doesn't send redirect_url in params TO Twitter, so I belive it is preset in Twitter configuration before. Same for Google. Go to oauth settings and fix them!

Comment: I am sure I configured everything correctly in oauth settings, I did not add :5050 port, on localhost everything works fine

Comment: So what is the value in Callback URL in your app? (https://apps.twitter.com, click name, go to Settings)

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel http://socpost.net/auth/twitter/callback/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omniauth in response included port used internally by nginx
this blog helped me a lot
http://awesomeprogrammer.com/blog/2012/12/09/dealing-with-omniauth-redirect-uri-mismatch-invalid-port-number-gotcha/

Comment: Thank you! This is so stupid, why don't they use `default_url_options` like everything else?

Comment: Switched to puma from passenger on heroku, added nginx support as well. And this issue came up, I was pulling my hairs. Thanks you!